# PAC2021 reports "Error while parsing the PDF document (Operator 'cm' is not allowed in this current state)" - but why?

Tags: pdf, accessibility, pdf-generation

I am using the [PAC2021 application](https://pdfua.foundation/en/pdf-accessibility-checker-pac/) to analyze some PDFs for compliance towards the PDF/UA standards.

For some files (all generated by the software of my company) the following error is reported:

*Error while parsing the PDF document (Operator 'cm' is not allowed in this current state)*

There are no further explanations, just this phrase. An example of PDF page content that raises the above error is:

```
/P << /MCID 0 >> BDC
  BT
    0 g
    1 0 0 1 81 639.75 cm
    /F0 10 Tf
    1 0 0 1 0 4.45 Tm
    (Hello, world!) Tj
  ET
EMC
```

Apparently PAC2021does not like the "cm" in the fourth line, but why?
I went through the documents of specifics for PDF and could not find an explanation on why this should be considered a syntax error. All PDF readers I have tried do not complain about such content, also I tried running the same document through Adobe Preflight for PDF/UA, it reported the document as fully compliant.

So I'm wondering: is this content violating a special restriction of the PDF/UA format? If so, where can I find its definition? Or is it an error in the PAC2021 report?

Comment: You aren't allowed to change certain parts of the graphics state insidde a text block, the CTM (altered by 'cm') is one of them. Many PDF readers ignore many types of invalid PDF file, because Acrobat does. Figure 4.1 on page 197 of the 1.7 PDF Reference shows what operations can be performed, but you need to look up which operations are 'general graphics state' and which are 'special graphics state'. Those are listed in Table 4.1 on page 196.

Comment: In case you want a link to the [1.7 PDF Reference](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/pdfreference1.7old.pdf)

Comment: This is still true for the PDF specifications ISO 32000-1 and ISO 32000-2 even though there has been a change in the category of "special graphics state" instructions in ISO 32000-2:2020.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I missed the distinction between 'general graphics state' and 'special graphics state', that explains the error. Thanks.